# How can I setup rules so I can write documents to firestore protected by uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make it so I can have authenticated users write to a collection that is only read/write/create-able to that user only. I'm struggling with the most basic Firestore setup. My firestore rules look like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{userId} {
      allow read, write, create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming this will prevent read/writes/creates to the database unless the initial part of the path matches the UID of the logged in user.

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
function addSomeData(data) {
    console.log( "Sending data with: ", user.uid, data );
    db.collection(user.uid).add({ data })
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
}
```

I definitely have user.id set correctly after successful login.

Using things this way always gives me this error in the console:

> Error adding document:  Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

If I revert to the original rules like this then the document is successfully created:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have each collection start with the UID of the logged in user. So, a sample shape of the data might be this:

```
/ax323/brty/data="Hello"
/ax323/98da/data="Goodbye"
/br981/ha31/data="No comment"
```

So, ax323 is a UID in Firebase, as is br981. ax323 has two documents in the collection, while br981 has one.

Is the "shape" of my data the problem?

I don't really understand what the `{document=**}` means in the original rules, and whether I need to convert my authentication rule to something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your database rules you have used  `match /users/{userId} {`
This rule will apply only to the document mathching that particular path.
So if your document path is `/ax323/brty/data` then your rules should be like

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write, create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Also looking at your question, I can't get what `brty` means when you mentioned

`/ax323/brty/data="Hello"` ?

Comment: brty is just the ID of the document created under the collection. Your suggestion works great! I'm still a little confused why I need to add {document=**} to the end, but it definitely works.